# Find a user with more processes running powershell

Tags: powershell

Help me please in writing a script - find a user with more processes running powershell.

I tried this option, but I'm not sure if the result is correct:

```
ps -IncludeUserName|? UserName -m "$env:USERNAME"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking to do.  You want to find the user with the most processes?

Comment: Yes! i want to find the user with the most processes

Comment: Is `ps` really an alias for `Get-Process`? You should be able to use `Group-Object` as a quick solution to this question. Also, the quotes around `$env:username` are not needed; although it is a good practice.

Comment: What is -`m`?  You can't shorten `-match`.

Comment: @js2010 You cannot shorten `-match` in _expression mode_, but you can in _argument_ mode, because with the [simplified syntax being](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax) being used, the operators are simply (switch) _parameters_, and abbreviating parameter names works just fine, as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous. That said, the usual recommendation applies: use abbreviations only _interactively_, not in scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the process objects you receive from `Get-Process` and use `Group-Object` to group them by UserName.  Then sort the groups you get back by the Count property and Select only the last object which will be the group with the  highest count of processes.  Supplying `-ExpandProperty Name` will return only the Name property of the group which contains the UserName (which is what we grouped on using `Group-Object`)

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
    Group-Object UserName | 
        Sort-Object Count | 
            Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```